# How to solve this differential equation; solution given, one approach also shown

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation that needs solving:

$\frac{dx}{dt}+\alpha x=\beta$

Then the solution is supposed to be:

$x=e^{-\alpha t}(C+\beta\int\limits_0^t e^{\alpha y}dy)$

However if I use the simple approach of substituting $z=\beta-\alpha x$, I have

$\frac{dz}{z}=-\alpha\ dt$

Simple integration gives answer which is different from desired solution.

$ln\ z=-\alpha t+C$

Comment: Do you know Laplace transform?

Comment: will have to google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln\ z=-\alpha t+C$$
$$ z=Ce^{-\alpha t}$$
$$ \beta-\alpha x=Ce^{-\alpha t}$$
$$ \alpha x=-Ce^{-\alpha t}+\beta$$
$$ x=-\dfrac C {\alpha }e^{-\alpha t}+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}$$
$$ x(t)=Ke^{-\alpha t}+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}$$
Looks the same for me.
$$x=e^{-\alpha t}(C+\beta\int\limits_0^t e^{\alpha y}dy)$$
$$x=e^{-\alpha t}(C+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}( e^{\alpha t}-1))$$
$$x=e^{-\alpha t}(C-\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha})+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}$$
This can ve rewritten as:
$$x(t)=Ke^{-\alpha t}+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}$$
It's the same answer. $K$ is just a constant.